# Affect on std::cout on performance of the program

Tags: c++, performance

I have written a program which would fetch file details and place them in the SQLite database.
In this process i have observed two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

1. Loop through each and every file and fill the file details(path) in
   to the database(sqlite3).
2. While for each file encountered,keep a counter and print the same
   via std::cout. Time taken to execute this program:30mins

**Scenario 2:**

1. Loop through each and every file and fill the file details(path) in
   to the database(sqlite3).

Time taken to execute this program:7mins

I am very unclear as of why just because of `std::cout`,the **time taken is 5 times more** than that of not printing it?

Any pointers on this scenario is highly appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Printing takes time - what's surprising about that?

Comment: Perhaps printf might be faster, if you want to try. Otherwise like Hulk said it :)

Comment: It takes 5 times the normal time?

Comment: [how many times do you use `std::endl` vs. `"\n"`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/819272)

Comment: i have used only the following code std::cout<<variable;

Answer (score 0):

try to use `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`, by default std::cout sync with stdio

Comment: Sure.Thanks.Will give a try and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Printing to console is costly. Usually more time-consuming than writing to a file.

I bet your code could run in less than a minute. Make sure you surround some inserts in [a transaction](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). You can also use multiple inserts in one statement, like explained in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database).

Comment: I have already been using transaction and auto vacuum options from sqlite3 db.I am only worried about why exactly the cout is taking more time(5 times)..